# Calculate the difference from 2 times

Tags: javascript, time, difference

Today I started working on something with times.

I have 2 times. The time from now in a string like 10:10:15 and a date in 27/02/2015 10:05:10.

So for this example I need 00:05:05 but I can't figure it out how I have to solve this one and I have searched for hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to parse the time string you have into a `Date` instance reliably cross-browser (even though it's not in the spec):

```
var dt = new Date("01/01/2015 " + timeString);
```

Or if you want to do it in-spec (but that won't work on older browsers, as the spec only added this in ES5):

```
var dt = new Date("2015-01-01T" + timeString + "Z");
dt = new Date(dt.getTime() + (dt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000));
```

In both cases, the input string's time is assumed to be *local* time (that's why we do the timezone adjustment). (We need the `"Z"` on the string because the ES5 specification had a flippin' big bug in it and said that leaving the timezone off implied GMT, when in ISO-8601 [which the format was based on] leaving off the timezone implies local time. The ES6 spec fixes this, but that means that right now, some engines do one thing, other engines do something else.)

Here's how to get minutes since midnight from a `Date` instance:

```
var minutes = dt.getHours() * 60 + dt.getMinutes();
```

From there, it's subtraction (subtract one date's minutes-since-midnight from the other), division (the `/` operator, to get hours), and remainder (the `%` operator, to get minutes within the hour). :-)

Alternately, you can use a library like MomentJS to do the work for you. But the above isn't much work.

Comment: Just what I needed. Only that it gave it in mm dd yyyy, but that was a quick fix. Thanks.